# Setting "document.cookie"

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, cookies

Trying to set cookie below ways and facing issues:

Option1:

```
document.cookie = name + "=" + value + "; expires=" + date.toUTCString() + "; path=/";
```

This sets value only till name=value when i recall document.cookie.

Option 2:

```
document.cookie = "${name}=value";   
document.cookie = "expires=${date.toUTCString()}";
document.cookie = "path=/";
```

This works fine and i am able to read all the values from cookie based on ";" split.

Why this odd behaviour?
And in sonarqube report it says assigning document.cookie like the one in option 2 is wrong and its a bug.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Only the key/value pairs are exposed from `document.cookie`

This is done using JavaScript Object Accessors

Option 1 is working, check your developer tools

Option 2 is actually not what you want. Each assignment creates a new cookie. Three of them are created with respectively `name`, expires and path as cookie names. What you see from `document.cookie` is misleading